# TFDUpdateSQL not posting updates on Datasnap server

Tags: delphi, datasnap, firedac

I am trying to setup a DataSnap server which provides data through an TFDQuery object.  The query pulls data from multiple tables so I require a TFDUpdateSQL objects to post the data to the DB.

I've managed to provide the data to the DataSnap Client, but when I ApplyUpdates through the ClientDataSet - it doesn't seem to effect the database.

I have tried the following tests:

1. TFDQuery, with a one table query and **no** TFDUpdateSQL object, updates work
2. TFDQuery, with a one table query and **a** TFDUpdateSQL object, updates don't work
3. TFDConnection + TFDQuery + TFDUpdateSQL to a standalone VLC application, with multiple table query, updates work.

Is it possible that the TFDUpdateSQL object cannot be used to update queries with more than one table over DataSnap...?

Delphi XE7

Windows 7

Comment: Do you get errors or some other message?  And are the different sql-statements in the TFDUpdateSQL (insert, update, delete ...) correctly provided?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! No error messages.  I did however put a showmessage on some events e.g. opening dataset and closing, which are called.  I also put an showmessage on the Apply Updates, but the showmessage never appears.  The components are copied and pasted between projects, so all SQL are identical.  Also I have been told that perhaps I should tick the option ResolveToDataset in the Provider on the Server Teir, which I have tried.